# how to click on element using selenium inside a for loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to find a specific day within a date selector, I used find_elements and made a for loop to go through the dates, now I need to click on the desired date, but when using .click() nothing happens.

```
data_inicial = browser.find_elements('xpath','/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]')

    for data in data_inicial:
        date = data.text
        print(date)
```

This code returns me all calendar dates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXBbP.png)

OK! But now I need to click on the desired date, and using something like the code below doesn't work

```
for data in data_inicial:
        if data.text == '1':
            data.click()
            break
```

this is date picker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMT8P.png)

here is the code part of the datapicker

```
<div class="MuiDialogContent-root MuiPickersModal-dialog">
   <div class="MuiPickersBasePicker-container">
      <div class="MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-regular MuiPickersToolbar-toolbar MuiPickersDatePickerRoot-toolbar MuiToolbar-gutters">
         <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiPickersToolbarButton-toolbarBtn" tabindex="0" type="button">
            <span class="MuiButton-label">
               <h6 class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersToolbarText-toolbarTxt MuiTypography-subtitle1">2023</h6>
            </span>
            <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
         </button>
         <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiPickersToolbarButton-toolbarBtn" tabindex="0" type="button">
            <span class="MuiButton-label">
               <h4 class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersToolbarText-toolbarTxt MuiPickersToolbarText-toolbarBtnSelected MuiTypography-h4 MuiTypography-alignCenter">11/05/2023</h4>
            </span>
            <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiPickersBasePicker-pickerView">
         <div>
            <div class="MuiPickersCalendarHeader-switchHeader">
               <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton" tabindex="0" type="button">
                  <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                     <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path d="M15.41 16.59L10.83 12l4.58-4.59L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
                  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
               </button>
               <div class="MuiPickersSlideTransition-transitionContainer MuiPickersCalendarHeader-transitionContainer">
                  <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-alignCenter">maio 2023</p>
               </div>
               <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton" tabindex="0" type="button">
                  <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                     <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path d="M8.59 16.59L13.17 12 8.59 7.41 10 6l6 6-6 6-1.41-1.41z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
                  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="MuiPickersCalendarHeader-daysHeader"><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">do</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">2ª</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">3ª</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">4ª</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">5ª</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">6ª</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-dayLabel MuiTypography-caption">sá</span></div>
         </div>
         <div class="MuiPickersSlideTransition-transitionContainer MuiPickersCalendar-transitionContainer">
            <div>
               <div class="MuiPickersCalendar-week">
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-hidden" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">30</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">1</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">2</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">3</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">4</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">5</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">6</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="MuiPickersCalendar-week">
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">7</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">8</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">9</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">10</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-current MuiPickersDay-daySelected" tabindex="0" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">11</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">12</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">13</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="MuiPickersCalendar-week">
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">14</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">15</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">16</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">17</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">18</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">19</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">20</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="MuiPickersCalendar-week">
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">21</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">22</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">23</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">24</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">25</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">26</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">27</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="MuiPickersCalendar-week">
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">28</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">29</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">30</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">31</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-hidden MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">1</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-hidden MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">2</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <div role="presentation">
                     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-hidden MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                           <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit">3</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you clicking on OK button after `data.click()`. If not, worth adding the code to click on OK button.

Comment: yes i did that. it didn't work, I use this system daily manually, when clicking on the date it automatically selects without having to click on ok

Comment: when adding this to the code it selects the current day which is the day that is already selected when opening the date picker. which shows he didn't actually select day 1

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it is public?

Comment: unfortunately it is internal, from my work.

Comment: you should add the html of the datepicker including the the dates content, will help to debug

Comment: I added the date picker code part

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly...
You already know the date you want.

just grab the XPATH of the date you want and:
After you 'find_element' of the date_picker, 'find_element' of date, then use .click()

Comment: yes, in fact the date will always be from the 1st to the current day. that's why I made the for loop, so that it goes through the elements until it finds the current day. but I'm still trying to make him select the date. My difficulty is just understanding why it doesn't select the day